# How can I get this program to loop indefinitely until the specific integer 4 is entered?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is a function of a larger Python program. How can I get it to loop continuously until "4" is entered? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
print("\nEnter a number (1) - (4). (4) terminates the program.")
choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

while((choice != 1) and (choice != 2) and (choice != 3) and (choice != 4)):
        choice = int(input("\nInvalid option. Enter a number from the menu: "))

if(choice == 1):
        f = open("dna1.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal:   {0}" .format(contents))

if(choice == 2):
        f = open("dna2.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}" .format(contents))

if(choice == 3):
        f = open("dna3.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}" .format(contents))

if(choice == 4):
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit
```

Comment: `sys.exit` is a function; call it like `sys.exit(0)` to indicate successful completion, or `sys.exit(1)` to indicate failed completion due to an error.

Comment: Wrap it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap all in a `while True`, also think about using `elif` as your choice will be one of all so don't to check the next one's if one successes, and you can simplify the `while/choice` using an array.

Also I'd suggest you refactor to avoid duplicate code (if you can) for the part that check mode, read file, save content, print content ;

```
while True:
    while choice not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        choice = int(input("\nInvalid option. Enter a number from the menu: "))

    if choice == 1:
        ...
    elif choice == 2:
        ...
    elif choice == 3:
        ...
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Or add an `else` at the end and remove the inner loop

```
while True:
    choice = int(input(" Enter a number from the menu: "))
    if choice == 1:
        ...
    elif choice == 2:
        ...
    elif choice == 3:
        ...
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("\nInvalid option. Enter a number from the menu: ")
```

Comment: The inner `while` loop can be replaced by an `else` clause on the `if` statement.

Comment: @chepner Yep, that's one of the other possible solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using continue and break statement, I mean instead of saying condition in the while loop, you could say

```
while(True):
      if(condition met):
           break
      elif(condition):
           continue
```

You should probably add continue under all statements except the last on

Answer (score 0):

You could improve this code, but as far as the question goes, simply wrap your initial loop into another loop.

```
print("\nEnter a number (1) - (4). (4) terminates the program.")
choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))


while True:

    while ((choice != 1) and (choice != 2) and (choice != 3) and (choice != 4)):
        choice = int(input("\nInvalid option. Enter a number from the menu: "))

    if (choice == 1):
        f = open("dna1.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal:   {0}".format(contents))

    if (choice == 2):
        f = open("dna2.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}".format(contents))

    if (choice == 3):
        f = open("dna3.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}".format(contents))

    if (choice == 4):
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved with basic indention in python 3 but you can also modify this like:

```py
# continues loop until specific key is pressed
    
choice=int(input("\nEnter a number (1) - (4). (4) terminates the program."))
    
while choice <= 4 :
    choice=int(input("\nInvalid option. Enter a number from the menu: "))

    if choice == 1 :
        f = open("dna1.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal:   {0}" .format(contents))

    elif choice == 2 :
        f = open("dna2.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}" .format(contents))

    elif choice == 3 :
        f = open("dna3.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print("\nOriginal: {0}" .format(contents))

    else :
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You question has already been throughly answered by others.

However, I wanted to take a minute to show you a few opportunities for improving your coding style. I rewrote your program, and made some notes on how these changes can make your life easier as a developer.

1. **Set constants to allow yourself to manipulate data on a single line instead of multiple places.** - I did this by using an `options` variable for printing out the options to the user *and* for determining what to do with each option.
2. **Make your loops as small as possible to increase readability.** - In this example, I moved all of the logic that processes a choice out to a function. Now any reader can tell that all I'm really doing in this loop is (1) prompting the user, then (2) processing the choice.
3. **Stick variables into strings** - If there is only a small variation in a string that gets repeated, make the variation into a variable & drop it into the string. This will speed up your coding *and* make your code more readable. That's where `choice` comes in this example.
4. **[Use fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)** - This isn't a *must*, but it's a continuation of the previous point. Plus, it's a good way to optimize your code and make string parsing/concatenation more readable.

I hope this is helpful for you as you're learning Python! Happy coding!

```
options = list(range(1, 5))
finished = False

def process_choice(choice):
    if choice not in options:
        print("Invalid option.\n")
        return False

    if(choice == 4):
        print("Exiting program.")
        return True

    with open(f"dna{choice}.txt", "r") as file:
        contents = file.read()
        print(f"\nOriginal: {contents}")
    return True


print(f"\nEnter a number {options}. (4) terminates the program.\n")

while not finished:
    choice = input("Enter a number from the menu: ")
    finished = process_choice(int(choice))
```